# Rails 405 Method not allowed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-405

I have a select box and on every change I am going back to my controller and fetching some data. This data is then loaded into a div.

jQuery:

```
   $('#groups').change(function() {
       $('#emails').load('/notifications/get', {value: $(this).val()});
  });
```

Controller:

```
  class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
      def get
        return "test"
      end
  end
```

View:

```
  <div id="groups" class="left">
<%=select_tag 'employee[group_id][]', options_for_select( current_user.groups.map {|s| ["#{s.name} - #{s.description} (" + s.employees.find(:all, :conditions=>{:subscribed=>true}).count.to_s+")", s.id]}), :multiple => true, :size =>6, :style  => "width:250px"%>
  </div>

  <p id="emails"> </p>
```

When I try to debug with firebug I see that error is `405 method not allowed` ..furthermore response that comes back says

> ```
> Only get, put, and delete
> requests are allowed.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a route set for that action?